# syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<--- this is my view-->
<?php 
    if ($exec == 'true'){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("email alreay exist");
        </script>'
    }
?>
<?php endif; ?>

<-- this is my controller -->
function email_taken($input){

    $query="select * from dentaldoctors  where email='$input'";
    $exec=$this->db->query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    if($exec) {
        true
    } else {
        FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: in your echo your missing ; at the end of the line

Comment: where did u begin the end if you are closing? and you missing a semi colon to terminate the echo statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the following doing?

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

You're closing a non existent if statement - based on the code you've given.

Comment: From the edit history it shows that the OP did not have that end if it shows that you are the one that put it there see  [Your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43864635/2) Against [OP's edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43864635/1)

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Actually, if you look at the source of the original post - http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73b2a8c0-598a-4cd9-b8d4-0eb7bd2604d4/view-source - you'll see that the `<?php endif; ?>` is already there. I just formatted it correctly.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile You've also therefore rolled back a completed fine edit. Do you know what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing semicolon in both of if statement

View

```
if ($exec == 'true'){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("email alreay exist");
    </script>';
}
```

Controller

```
if($exec) {
    true;
} else {
    FALSE;
}
```

Please replace your code as per above explanation. i hope it will work for you !

Answer (score 0):

**SIMPLE ANSWER. REMOVE THE `<?php endif; ?>` FROM YOUR CODE AND IT WORKS LIKE A CHARM. ALSO, ADD `;` AT THE END OF `echo` STATEMENT**

Comment: Why so shouty??

Comment: All answers just focus on the `;` and useless things. They don't see the question asked by the OP and the error produced to OP